# how to transfer data from one html page to another without using forms and input tags

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, css

For e.g; following is the html snippet for the short summary of hotel rooms in HotelRooms.html

```
<div class="Room1"  onclick="window.location.href='RoomDescription.html'">
        <div class="roomInfoaltered">
          Luxury room 1 <br>
          <span style="font-size:18px; font-family:Tillana">PKR 4,250</span>
        </div>
      </div>

<div class="Room2" onclick="window.location.href='RoomDescription.html'">
        <div class="roomInfoaltered">
          Twin room 3 <br>
          <span style="font-size:18px; font-family:Tillana">PKR 8,250</span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I want to get the values of either div I click on RoomDescription.html page. How can i send Info as Room Type="Twin room 3" and price="8250" from HotelRooms page to RoomDescription page. Moreover how to get the parameter values on RoomDescription.html page. I realize the form method is much convenient but didn't learned it till now after designing my whole page.

Comment: Just add to the url -> `RoomDescription.html?room=3&price=300`

Comment: @adeneo and how can i get these param on the next page. Through javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use cookies to do so, but based on the context of your post, that would not be a good idea as cookies can be modified by the user. The best option is honestly forms, and practically all of the ways I can think of transferring data between pages besides that can be targeted and modified.